# How to simplify an expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

I have tried to simplify this expression for quite a long time now but I can't find how to do it.

$$\left(\frac{1}{2+4m}-\frac{1-m}{8m^3+1}:\frac{1-2m}{2m^2-2m+1}\right)\cdot\frac{4m+2}{2m-1}-\frac{1}{1-4m+4m^2}$$

Can someone help me with it?

Comment: What is the symbol $(:)$ between second and the third time?

Comment: @tatan I think it means division

Comment: I'd do: **1.** eliminate the fraction $(:)$. **2.** Make one fraction of the terms between brackets. **3.** Multiply with the fraction outside the brackets. **4.** Make one fraction of the result and the last fraction. In that order. Hope it helps.

Comment: @tatan          It is division.

Answer (score 1):

$\require{cancel}$
Starting with the original expression:

$$\left(\frac{1}{2+4m}-\frac{1-m}{8m^3+1}:\frac{1-2m}{2m^2-2m+1}\right)\cdot\frac{4m+2}{2m-1}-\frac{1}{1-4m+4m^2}$$

Factoring where possible and changing the order of some terms:

$$\left(\frac{1}{2(2m+1)}+\frac{m-1}{(2m+1)(4m^2-2m+1)}:\frac{-(2m-1)}{2m^2-2m+1}\right)\cdot\frac{2(2m+1)}{2m-1}-\frac{1}{(2m-1)^2}$$

Converting division into multiplication by the reciprocal; distributing the outside fraction:

$$\left(\frac{1}{2(2m+1)}\frac{2(2m+1)}{2m-1}+\frac{m-1}{(2m+1)(4m^2-2m+1)}\frac{2m^2-2m+1}{-(2m-1)}\frac{2(2m+1)}{2m-1}\right)-\frac{1}{(2m-1)^2}$$

Some cancellations:

$$\hspace{-0.8mm}\left(\frac{1}{\cancel{2(2m+1)}}\frac{\cancel{2(2m+1)}}{2m-1}+\frac{m-1}{\cancel{(2m+1)}(4m^2-2m+1)}\frac{2m^2-2m+1}{-(2m-1)}\frac{2\cancel{(2m+1)}}{2m-1}\right)-\frac{1}{(2m-1)^2}$$

$$\implies\frac{1}{2m-1}-\frac{2(m-1)}{4m^2-2m+1}\frac{2m^2-2m+1}{(2m-1)^2}-\frac{1}{(2m-1)^2}$$

Finding common denominators:

$$\frac{8m^3-8m^2+4m-1}{(4m^2-2m+1)(2m-1)^2}-\frac{4m^3-8m^2+6m-2}{(4m^2-2m+1)(2m-1)^2}-\frac{4m^2-2m+1}{(4m^2-2m+1)(2m-1)^2}$$

Adding/subtracting:

$$\frac{4m^3-4m^2}{(4m^2-2m+1)(2m-1)^2}$$

Factoring one last time:

$$\frac{4m^2(m-1)}{(4m^2-2m+1)(2m-1)^2}$$